# Minimum number of edges needed to be removed to make a graph triangle-free

Tags: graph-theory

I got this question and I'm not sure how to solve it. There is a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and it has $cn^3$ triangles. Show that one needs to remove at least $cn^2$ edges from $G$ in order to make it triangle-free.

I thought of using Turán's theorem but did not succeed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Every edge you remove was part of at most $n-2$ different triangles.

Comment: Thanks! Using the hint it became a matter of simle equation-solving of
k*(n-2)>cn^3, can't belive its that simple.